# having trouble with the tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitableview

im dynamically adding content to the table, (grid of 2 images with a button and copy for each image... (0,1), (2,3), (4,5), (6,7), (8,9) ) the problem im having is that it IS loading all the images, but not all the buttons, instead its loading (0,1)...(4,5) and then repeating (0,1),(2,3) instead of showing (6,7), (8,9).

http://midnitefx.net/midnite/iPhoneTest/grid.zip

any help will be good

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two things in consideration here.... are u using drawrect to redraw the same view again or are u shifting to another view...

In both cases, i think you NEED to declare buttons as UIButtons and programmatically just change the image and reference ...just declare ONE button... hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the response, im a bit of a noob to obj-c. i am already declaring the buttons as a UIButton. i guess what im trying to do is... in: if (cell == nil) create all my buttons add them to an array (to reference them later), but the problem im running into is instead of displaying (0-9) buttons its only showing (0-5) and then repeating (0-3), hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

to start off....cell==nil means that either cell is not declared or its pointing to nothing... i hope thats what exactly ur trying to do there..

use NSLog() to check if ur array has all the elements (all 9 buttons)... u can run a for loop to check that and check through the console in xcode...after confirmation now see if u r drawing all 9 buttons within the DIMENSIONS of iphone screen which is 320 * 460... and u wont have any problems..

my opinion is that u have not filled you array properly so what i would suggest u is that make a temporary array just before u have to display the buttons, CONFIRM again throgh interface builder that all ur connections are fine ...i would suggest to use NSMutableArray....remember to put the last object "nil" in this array...

hope this helps